# flutter code formatting in vscode like in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

In Android Studio when you have Column of widgets it is very convenient to collapse the code like :

[image]

But in VSCode you cannot see the if there is a coma in the end, and even add it in collapsed mode.

[image]

Can VSCode be configured to show the closing brace and comma for folded code on the folded line, similar to Android Studio?

Comment: what are you trying to ask?